# Destructuring of the object returned by mongodb query result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say we start a mongodb query statement as the following:

```js
const user = await db.users.findOne(...);
console.log(user);
```

The result is good.

```js
{
  _id: 5f60647c28b90939d0e5fb24,
  tenantId: '5e6f7c86e7158b42bf500371',
  username: 'aaaa',
  email: 'xxxx@yy.com',
  createdAt: 2020-09-15T06:51:40.531Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-09-15T06:51:40.531Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Then we use destructuring.

```js
const { _id, username, ...others } = user;
console.log(others);
```

We get a weird thing:

```js
[
  [
    '$__',
    InternalCache {
      strictMode: false,
      selected: [Object],
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      saving: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5f60647c28b90939d0e5fb24,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      cachedRequired: {},
      session: undefined,
      '$setCalled': Set(0) {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': [Object]
    }
  ],
  [ 'isNew', false ],
  [ 'errors', undefined ],
  [ '$locals', {} ],
  [ '$op', null ],
  [
    '_doc',
    {
      _id: 5f60647c28b90939d0e5fb24,
      tenantId: '5e6f7c86e7158b42bf500371',
      username: 'aaaa',
      email: 'xxxx@yyy.com',
      createdAt: 2020-09-15T06:51:40.531Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-09-15T06:51:40.531Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  [ '$init', true ]
]
```

What's going on here? And how to make destructuring work again? There is the same error on `Object.entries(others)`.
There is one workaround, I can stringify it and then parse it back. But this is obviously redundant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the [Mongoose Document class](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Document). That's why you get the weird result after destructuring. In your case, you should use [.lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)
on your query to get expected result;

Comment: It is too weird. I suggest that Mongoose should return plain javascript object by default and return Mongoose Document class by .Mdc().

Answer (score 7):

this works for me :

```
const user = UserModel.findOne({...});
const { _id, username, ...others } = user.toObject();
```